# Put variable in Yfinance with Python

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, yfinance

Good evening everyone,

Small question ... I use Python and in particular the y.finance library (Yahoo Finance) which allows to extract financial data. When using this package, an expected format is predefined. It should be like this: ('year-month-day')
I would like to replace the "year" with an "a" variable that the program user can enter a little higher up. However, this sends me an error message telling me that the format ('year-month-day') is not respected, while "a" has entered the year format.

Here is my script:

```
import yfinance as yf
a=int(input("A partir de quelle année voulez-vous commencer le scraping de données?\n"))
#définir ticker
cac='^FCHI'
#récupération des données
data=yf.Ticker(cac)
#récupération prix
dataDF= data.history(periode='1d', start='a-1-1', end='2022-1-1')

#afficher les données pour le CAC 40
dataDF
```

**Do you have a solution ??**

Thank you in advance for your answers !!

Comment: Note ```start='a-1-1'``` is a string definition it doesn't involve the variable a.  Try ```start = f"{a}-1-1"```.

Comment: thanks ! you're a genius !